# I am not able to do execute update in the while loop

Tags: java

```
String re = "inCart";
String sre = "Sold";
resultSetP = statement.executeQuery("select * from shoppingcart where proStatus='" + re + "' and customerID='" + this.customerID + "'");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    int ed = statement.executeUpdate("update shoppingcart set proStatus='" + sre + "'  where proStatus='" + re + "' and customerID='" + this.customerID + "'");
}

resultSetS = statement.executeQuery("select * from shoppingcart where serStatus='" + re + "' and customerID='" + this.customerID + "'");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    int efd = statement.executeUpdate("update shoppingcart set serStatus='" + sre + "' where serStatus='" + re + "' and customerID='" + this.customerID + "'");
}
```

Comment: code only answers are frowned upon. It makes it very difficult for us to know what your question actually is. Provide an explanation of what problem you're having, and what you have already tried to do to fix it/identify the problem.

Comment: add some explanation ?what you are trying ?what the error you get?This would be helpful for you because you get more chances to get answer if you explain well

Comment: I am trying to update my table in database using statement.executeupdate in while loop. Can I use statement.execute update in while(resultSet.next)

Comment: first while loop executes only one time, it should execute thrice as per my table data. and 2nd while loop is not executing at all. Directly it is going in to the catch block and throwing error.

Comment: what is `resultSet`?

Comment: Are you familiar with named query parameters?

Comment: Why would you want to do the update in a loop? Write the where condition of the update statement so at it affects all rows that need to be updated. And use a PreparedStatement with parameters!!!!

Comment: The values of `sre`, `re`, and `this.customerID` never change, so your loops are useless.  Even if they were to execute multiple times, you're running exactly the same query every time.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you write inside the loop conditions *resultSet.next()* maybe it should be *resultSetS.next()* or *resultSetP.next()*

Comment: It is resultSet only instead of p and s in each statement.

Comment: if you put the same conditions in both loops, in the second loop you'll never execute it.  And probably your first loop is being executed several times, but is always the same query...  Can you print the value of ed in the System.out to Know How many times is executed?

Comment: @maiklahoz  if `customerID` is FK then I suppose each update will execute from 0 to 1 times, depending on occurrence of customer with given ID and status.

Comment: YEs first while loop is executed 3 times but second loop never executed

Comment: Normal, because you are evaluating the same resultSet that in your first loop, and if you are exiting of your first loop, is beacuse the condition is false, so in the second loop, the condition is false too.

Answer (score -1):

Try using resultSet.hasNext() instead of resultSet.next(). So effectively your code should be like the below while iterating through the resultset

```
while (resultset.hasNext()) {
      resultset.next();
     //Your query
}
```

Comment: there is nothing like resultset.hasNext()